# Create .zip in C# and add xml file in it

Tags: c#, file-io, zip

I want to create a .zip file in C# and after that I want to put a xml file in it.

This is what I tried but it doesn't work.

I have a folder like, archieve -> 2040 -> and here I want to create the archieve

```
private void WriteXmlArchieveProductOnDisk(string identifier, string pathInFolder, byte[] xmlFile)
{
    string folderName = Path.Combine("Resources", pathInFolder, _baseService.CurrentCompanyId().ToString());
    string pathToSave = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), folderName);

    if (!Directory.Exists(pathToSave))
    {
        Directory.CreateDirectory(pathToSave);
    }

    string fileNameWithoutExtension = $"{Guid.NewGuid()}_{identifier}";
    string fileNameWithExtension = $"{fileNameWithoutExtension}.xml";
    List<string> existing = Directory.EnumerateFiles(pathToSave).Where(file => Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file) == fileNameWithoutExtension).ToList();

    if (existing.Count > 0)
    {
        foreach (var file in existing)
        {
            FileD.Delete(file);
        }
    }

    using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
    {
        using (var archive = new ZipArchive(ms, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
        {
            var zipArchiveEntry = archive.CreateEntry(fileNameWithExtension);
            using (var entryStream = zipArchiveEntry.Open())
            using (var fileToCompressStream = new StreamWriter(entryStream))
            {
                fileToCompressStream.Write(xmlFile);
            }
        }
        using (var fileStream = new FileStream($"{pathToSave}", FileMode.Create))
        {
            ms.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);
            ms.CopyTo(fileStream);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What does `but doesn't work` mean? You get an error? Empty file? Bad archive?

Comment: Besides, if you want to write to a file there's no reason to use a `MemoryStream`

Comment: I get 'acces to the path .... is denied' but in that folder i add other files , pdf and other typres, and for that it work, now i want to develope this method, for .zip.  In this method it work if i add only xml in the folder, if i want to make an archeive and add it to the folder i get that error

Comment: `StreamWriter` is used to write text to a stream.  In this case you already have the file's contents in `byte[] xmlFile`. You can write that array directly to `entryStream`.  `fileToCompressStream.Write(xmlFile)` will try to serialize the bytes as text, producing an invalid entry

Comment: Post the actual *full* exception text, including the call stack, in the question itself. Do you get the error when deleting files or when saving the ZIP?  If `pathToSave` is a folder path, ` new FileStream($"{pathToSave}", FileMode.Create)` will always fail - you can't open a stream on directories, only on files